# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8:

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

While creating dynamic link (short link) firebase is throwing following Exception:
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8:..

1 week before creation of dynamic link was working perfectly, suddenly getting this issue. is there any solution to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a known issue that's been asked from the support. According to them, there are currently two workarounds for this issue:

- Use the Dynamic Link version **16.0.1** to be able to generate a short Dynamic Link
- Stick in using version **16.1.1**, create a long link first then try to shorten the long Dynamic Link using this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create#shorten-a-long-dynamic-link)